# iPad iPod app album flip effect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

Does anyone know how to implement the album flip effect in the iPod application on iPad? I want to have this effect when presenting a modal view controller.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should help http://www.chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.m